# Model passed to Web Api 2 method is null - AngualrJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm calling a method inside my Web Api 2 controller, passing in a model called login which consists of EmailAddress and Password.  However it hits the method but the model passed in is always null...

My call from AngularJs function :

```
  var login = { "EmailAddress": emailAddress, "Password": password };

    $http.post("/api/Login/", { headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': $scope.antiForgeryToken } }, login).success(function () {

        alert('succes');

    }).error(function () {

        alert('Unable to login at present, please try again later');

    });
```

My method:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void Post([FromBody]Login login)
    {
        var t = login.EmailAddress;
    }
```

I think its something to do with how I've structure my actual Angular $http.post method but again I'm not sure, can anyone suggest would could potentially be wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use ajax and Razor?

```
    var login = { "EmailAddress": emailAddress, "Password": password };
    $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("api/login", "Controller", login)",
                type: "GET",
                data: {},
                success: fCheckBoxes
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why cannot add the token to every request by configuring your app.js

```
// Set header for every request
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor',  function ($localStorage) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {                
            if ($localStorage.token != null)
                config.headers['myAppToken'] = $localStorage.token;

            return config;
        }
    };
});

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});
```